# undefined method `keys' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Why when you iterate through a serialized JSON hash but spits out that the class is `nil`?

#### View

```
<% @test.yo.keys.each do |key| %>
  <%= key %>
<% end %>
```

#### Model

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :city
  serialize :yo, JSON
end
```

Comment: undefined method `keys' for nil:NilClass  Extracted source (around line #52):  52: <% @test.yo.keys.each do |key|%>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's saying that yo is nil for @test. you need to check yo for nil before you call a method against it :

```
<% if !@test.yo.nil? %>
  <% @test.yo.keys.each do |key| %>
    <%= key %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

you can probably find a better place to put your check, but this gives you an idea of how to fix it

Comment: yoo thank's Chris! but just one doubt, is a problem call a method on a nil class?

Comment: nil doesn't define a method "keys" so you can't call nil.keys.  something simpler, like maybe nil.to_s would work. but you can't call just any method against nil.

Comment: humm interesting, ill look toward this. thank you very much Chris.